# How to plot pivot chart in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pivottable.js

Currenly, I am new in python scripting I am using panda, pivottablejs for creating a script. I have one csv file and I read that csv file using panda and I got the table like this.
[image]

Now, I want to generate the pivotchart using pivottablejs so for that I have to pass dataframe object in the pivot_ui();

I want to Plot in Pivot Chart the total number of issue status created for every OriginationPhase.

So I tried something like this.

```
LabelsReviewedByDate = issues_df.groupby(['Status','OriginationPhase'])

pivot_ui(LabelsReviewedByDate)
```

I know this is wrong but I am new in python scripting. So help me to find the solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass the dataframe right to pivot_ui:

```
import pandas as pd
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui

a= [ [1,'Requirements','bug'],[2,'Design','bug'],[3,'Testing','bug'],[4,'Requirements','bug'],[5,'Requirements','Inquiry'] ]

df  = pd.DataFrame(a,columns =['Issue#','OriginationPhase','Category'])

pivot_ui(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but I got only one column in my pivot chart @Andrew L

Comment: Yes I tried above code. I just copied and paste it. @Andrew L

Comment: in my bar chart it only display 1 bar the value of that bar is 5. @Andrew L

Answer (score 1):

The pivot_table method comes to solve this problem. It works like pivot, but it aggregates the values from rows with duplicate entries for the specified columns

```
a= [ [1,'Requirements','bug'],[2,'Design','bug'],[3,'Testing','bug'],[4,'Requirements','bug'],[5,'Requirements','Inquiry'] ]

df  = pd.DataFrame(a,columns =['Issue#','OriginationPhase','Category'])
df.pivot_table( index = 'Category',columns = 'OriginationPhase',aggfunc = lambda x: len(x) )  )

                 Issue#                     
OriginationPhase Design Requirements Testing
Category                                    
Inquiry             NaN            1     NaN
bug                   1            2       1
```

Comment: Thank you for reply@galaxyan. I have one more doubt that I want to make pivot chart for total number of issue status created for every OriginationPhase so for that I need to use
a= [ [1,'Requirements','Approved'],[2,'Design','Completed'],....

df  = pd.DataFrame(a,columns =['Issue#','OriginationPhase','Category'])
df.pivot_table( index = 'Category',columns = 'OriginationPhase').

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MithilAmin  if you need status, just change  to  df.pivot_table( index = 'Status',columns = 'OriginationPhase',aggfunc = lambda x: len(x) )

Comment: I replaced it with 'Status' and I got the error. labels ['Status'] not contained in axis